# How to assign a pointer to object to another pointer to object of same class?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class called `arr` and it has a function named `_union` written like this:

```
template<class T>
arr<T> *arr<T>::_union(arr<T> B) {
    arr<T> *C(this->length + B._length());
    bool isPresent = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        C->push_back(this->get(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < B._length(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < C->_length(); k++) {
            if (B.get(j) == C->get(k))
                isPresent = true;
        }
        if (!isPresent)
            C->push_back(B.get(j));
        isPresent = false;
    }

    return C;
}
```

The function returns a pointer of an object that was newly created inside this function's scope.

In main function, I wrote code like this :

```
arr<int> *a3 = a1._union(a2);
a3->display();
```

When I run, this gives me an error:

[image]

What is the problem here? If I don't use any pointers and just return normal object then everything is fine.

Please help me. Also I don't have any copy constructers inside the class. I am just trying to create my own array class with data and functions.

Comment: Note: The `length` in `C` will be wrong in those cases where the containers contain elements that compare equal (since you don't `push_back` duplicates).

Comment: I am using two data variables for this class i.e. SIZE and LENGTH. SIZE is max limit and LENGTH is current size.

Comment: The constructor is taking SIZE, but push_back increases length by 1, which was initially 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
arr<T> *C(this->length + B._length());
```

`C` is a pointer and `this->length + B._length()` is an integer, hence the error. You can't assign an integer to a pointer.

I guess you were trying to write this code

```
arr<T> *C = new arr<T>(this->length + B._length());
```

This code allocates a new `arr<T>` object using `new` and calls the a constructor for that object using the integer parameter `this->length + B._length()`.

However is usually a bad idea to use dynamic allocation like this. You should think about redesigning your function without using pointers.

```
template<class T>
arr<T> arr<T>::_union(arr<T> B) {
    arr<T> C(this->length + B._length());
    ...
    return C;
}
```

This will require you to define a copy constructor etc for `arr<T>`. But that is normal C++ programming you shouldn't be reluctant to do it.

Comment: Oh yeah. Writing such huge class might have made me forgot small things. Thank you so much. P.S. I am new to programming :).

Comment: @Bhuvansai: be careful... quite a big part of programming is about small things (details). A fantastic design can still end up in horrible software if most details are not right.